# Redo a git merge

Tags: git, merge, repeat

I have a remote master branch and a local called "feature". I have merged in from master before and did multiple changes on the local branch. I haven't pushed it back up to master though. So when I try to "git pull", it only says "Everything is up-to-date". 
On the other hand the files in "master" and the files in "feature" are different, and I want to get rid of several files locally that we have, but master doesn't. 
What I need is a way to pull master again and flag up every file as a conflict, so I can choose what I need and what I don't. 
Rerolling the local changes is not an option as I would lose all my code I implemented. 
Thanks for the help!

Comment: "I want to get rid of several files locally that we have, but master doesn't." => did you add these files in `feature`? Did `master` remove them? Before, or after you merged from `master`?

Answer (score 1):

You need to make the distinction between branches (`master`, `feature`, you `merge` and `pull`), and `remotes` (required to `pull`, and related to the message `Everything is up-to-date`). It's not very clear what your situation is, where are you trying to `pull` from? And what branch?

As far as I understand, you have a history where everything in the branch `master` is already merged in the branch `feature`

If you are running `git pull` while you have the branch `feature` checked out, `git` tries to `fetch` new commits from a `remote` repo, then merge them (if any) to `feature`. This assumes that `feature` has a remote tracking branch, but if the command is working at all (with no arguments), it probably has one.

Since `git pull` says that `feature` is up-to-date, it seems that you have already pushed the branch `feature` to its remote tracking branch (to a remote repo). You pull, it tells you nothing more happened.

On the other hand, you may mean that `master` is up-to-date.

If you want to "get rid of several files locally that we have" (in `feature`, I suppose), then what stops you from just deleting them? `git rm <file to get ridden of>`. Do that while on `feature`, and you won't affect `master`. Commit as you normally would.

If you have changes in `feature` that you want to discard, and get the files as they are in master, you can `git checkout master -- <file to get>`. This updates your local file to its `master` state, but without changing branch, you are still on `feature`. Create new commits with these updated files, on `feature`.

What you also can do is an interactive rebase. `git rebase` records the changes in `feature` and lets you "replay" them on top of another (or the same) commit. In addition to that, `git rebase --interactive` lets you skip commits in the replay phase, and even *edit* what a commit does before replaying it. For example, you could modify a commit in the replay phase, not to add the unnecessary files.

Simplest would be the `git checkout master -- <file>`, if just removing the unnecessary files does not work.

Answer (score 0):

Try a `git reset HEAD~1` to make git think it is a commit back in history (or change 1 if master's changes span multiple overlapping commits), followed by `git pull …`.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for your answers!
What I have ended up doing is:
1. checked out master
2. physically copy every folder master has into a different location
3. checked out feature
4. start a folder compare with "beyond compare" and one by one edited each files sometimes taking feature's changes, sometimes master's.

This is not really a git solution, and took a while, but it worked :)